# windows could not start the service on local computer error 1067 on windows server 2008 SP1

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-error-reporting

I have built a window application which i am trying to turn into service. 
I am easily able to install it but when i try to run that service , it shows:

**Windows could not start the service on local computer error 1067. The process terminated unexpectedly**.

In the event view property logs , error with event id 7034 is seen but no error description. 
Already searched a lot for solution but no success.

Comment: Error 1067 is `ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED`, which means *The process terminated unexpectedly*. With absolutely no useful information, it's highly unlikely we'll be able to help. Use the debugger. or do some logging to a text file or the debug window to try and see what's happening.

Comment: Visual Studio allows to attach a procces for debugging only when service is running. I am not able to reach that stage. Is there any way i can print logs to event logs

Answer (score 2):

I also got same error some time back.
This error has several reasons.
One reason can be u are specifying some path to the file or location which the service is unable to read or write after it is installed.

Comment: I got this when I installed ISC Bind for Windows and tried to start it as Windows Service. This answer made me check etc directory under Bind installation directory. It was empty. When I populated with necessary files from another installation, the service started fine.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when the compilation target CPU differs from the server CPU type.

*Ex. running x86 built service on x64 server,*

Make sure you build the project with the correct target CPU or with AnyCPU.

*Visual Studio -> Project properties -> Compile -> (Select configuration) -> Target CPU -> **AnyCPU***

Comment: Um. That's nonsense. I've been running x86 services on x64 systems for ages. It works fine.