# Installing a Tcl application as a Windows Service error

Tags: windows-services, tcl, tcldevkit

I'm trying to install a Tcl program as a service on my Windows machine using the TclDevKit's TclServiceManager. I'm following the guide [here](http://docs.activestate.com/tdk/3.2/ServMgr.html) step by step and yet I am experiencing a lot of issues.

If I try to use my raw .tcl file to create the service, I get the following error:

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

I've followed a solution for this issue [here](https://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000071019-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion-when-attempting-to-start-stop-or-pause) to give the program more time to start up before the Service Control Manager terminates it; to no avail.

Then I decided to try and wrap the program using TclApp and see if that worked. Like the guide says, I used the `base-tclsvc-win32-ix86.exe` prefix file located in my TclDevKit bin directory. Installing the service that way, and then trying to run it resulted in the following error:

```
Windows could not start the <service name> service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

There wasn't much information at all that I could find googling this error. The only Stackoverflow post on it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941659/windows-could-not-start-the-service-on-local-computer-error-1067-on-windows-serv) one. So I tried installing the service manually through the command prompt using `<TheProgram>.exe <Service Name> -install` and tried running it - still gave me the same error.

Then I tried to see if I could get any useful information by running `<TheProgram>.exe <Service Name> -debug` and interestingly enough I got the following output:

```
Debugging <Service Name>. 
InitTypes: failed to find the DictUpdateInfo AuxData type

abnormal program termination
```

Googling `InitTypes: failed to find the DictUpdateInfo AuxData type` leads me nowhere, however it seems to be something Tcl related.

Finally, if it means anything, the source code for the program I was trying to install as a service is some simple web server code:

```
proc Serve {chan addr port} {
    fconfigure $chan -translation auto -buffering line 
    set line [gets $chan]
    set path [file join . [string trimleft [lindex $line 1] /]]
    if {$path == "."} {set path ./index.html}

    if {[catch {
        set f1 [open $path]
    } err]} {
        puts $chan "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"
    } else {
        puts $chan "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
        puts $chan "Content-Type: text/html"
        puts $chan ""
        puts $chan [read $f1]
        close $f1
    }

    close $chan
}

if {![info exists reload]} {
    set sk [socket -server Serve 3000]
    puts "Server listening on port 3000"
    vwait forever
} else {
    unset reload
}
```

To check and see if the source code was the problem, I tried another, simpler example that simply created a file in a particular directory:

```
set filePath "C:/some/path/here";
set fileName "Test.txt";

set file [open [file join $filePath $fileName] w];
puts $file "Hello, World";

close $file;
```

Both programs work if you simply source them from tclsh86.exe, but give the above errors if you try and run them as services unwrapped and wrapped respectively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a bad idea to use `puts "Server listening on port 3000` inside a service, as you do not have a working stdout by default. That would explain the 'terminates unexpectedly'.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try removing it and see if it works! Goodness, if that's the problem I will be so relieved and annoyed haha.